# Common access to UDP socket in GCDAsyncUdpSocket from all ViewControllers

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, grand-central-dispatch, gcdasyncsocket

I am developing an iPad app which uses GCDAsyncUdpSocket.  The app has multiple view controllers and I need to access the UDP socket in various view controllers.  I am new to use GCD and the Async UDP Library.

What is the best technique to use to allow all view controllers to send and receive UDP messages?